# Cogroup on Spark DataFrames

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 large DataFrames to be merged based on a association key. Using `join` takes a longer time to complete the task.

I see that using `cogroup` is prefered over Joins in Apache Spark.  Can anyone point on how to use `cogroup` on DataFrames or suggest a better approach for merging 2 large DataFrames.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Spark >= 3.0**

Since 3.0 Spark provides PySpark-specific `cogroup` using Pandas / Arrow. General syntax is as follows:

```py
left.cogroup(right).apply(f)
```

where `both` and `right` are `GroupedData` objects and `f` is a `COGROUPED_MAP` User Defined Function that takes two Pandas `DataFrames` and returns Pandas `DataFrame`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame as PandasDataFrame

@pandas_udf(schema)
def f(left: PandasDataFrame, right: PandasDataFrame) -> PandasDataFrame: ...
```

**Spark >= 1.6**

JVM `KeyValueGroupedDataset` provides both Java

```java
def cogroup[U, R](other: KeyValueGroupedDataset[K, U], f: CoGroupFunction[K, V, U, R], encoder: Encoder[R]): Dataset[R]
```

and Scala

```scala
def cogroup[U, R](other: KeyValueGroupedDataset[K, U])(f: (K, Iterator[V], Iterator[U]) ⇒ TraversableOnce[R])(implicit arg0: Encoder[R]): Dataset[R]
```

It is  however intended for "strongly" typed variants, not `Dataset[Row]`, and is [highly unlikely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40596638/10465355) to contribute to your declared goal (performance improvement).

**Spark < 1.6** (this part stays valid onward, with exception to small API additions listed above).

`DataFrame` doesn't provide any equivalent of `cogroup` function and complex objects are not the first class citizens in the Spark SQL. A set of operations available on complex structures is rather limited so typically you have to either create custom expression what is not trivial or use UDFs and pay a performance penalty. Moreover Spark SQL doesn't use the same `join` logic as plain `RDDs`.

Regarding RDDs. While there exist border cases where `cogroup` can be favorable over `join` but typically it shouldn't be the case unless the results -> Cartesian product of complete dataset. After all joins on RDDs are expressed using `cogroup` followed by `flatMapValues` and since the latter operation is local the only real overhead is creation of the output tuples.

If your tables contain only primitive types you could mimic co-group like behavior by aggregating columns with `collect_list` first but I wouldn't expect any performance gains here.

Comment: There are a lot of cases where ```cogroup``` is favorable over ```join```. ```Cogroup``` is a join operator with ```groupBy``` semantics, it's very useful to put data in context. Complex objets are not yet first class citizens in Spark, but they yield tremendous performance benefits in impala by removing need for joins at read time.

Comment: @jwinandy  Can you elaborate as I have trust in zero323 comments.